# How to show parts of the generated list in range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im making a little list generator of number the code works but i want to show the first value(460) in the first line and the last. Is it possible to do that?

Here is what i can generate with my code.

> 460-2-401-1
>
> 460-2-402-2
>
> 460-2-403-3
>
> 460-2-404-4
>
> 460-2-405-5

And here is how i want it to look.

> 460-2-401-1
>
> 2-402-2
>
> 2-403-3
>
> 2-404-4
>
> 460-2-405-5

This is my code so far.

```
steps  =  0
for parts in range(5):
    print('{}-{}-{}-{}\n'.format(460, 2, 401 + steps , parts+1))
    steps +=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an if statement -- if it's first or last, add 460- to the start:

```
steps  =  0
for parts in range(5):
    print(('460-' if parts in [0, 4] else '') + '{}-{}-{}\n'.format(2, 401 + steps , parts+1))
    steps +=1
```

Or if you need it to be modular:

```
steps  =  0
for parts in range(n):
    print(('460-' if parts in [0, n - 1] else '') + '{}-{}-{}\n'.format(2, 401 + steps , parts+1))
    steps +=1
```

Comment: Well you have to define n. Put "n=5" before the script.

Comment: Why do you need the `steps` at all? Just replace it with `parts` and skip the assigning and increment.  `for parts in range(5):
    print(('460-' if parts in [0, 4] else '') + '{}-{}-{}\n'.format(2, 401 + parts , parts+1))` This works just as well.

Comment: @Idlehands Good point. I was assuming the OP was using the steps variable somewhere else, but that may not be the case.